# Failed assertion: line 1873 pos 12: 'hasSize': is not true with ListTile

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a Todo List with Draggable items with components below:

```
class DraggableListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const DraggableListItem({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TodoItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoItem(
      {Key? key,
      required this.todo,
      required this.updateTodo,
      required this.deleteTodo})
      : super(key: key);

  final Todo todo;
  final void Function(Todo) updateTodo;
  final void Function(Todo todo) deleteTodo;

  @override
  _TodoItemState createState() => _TodoItemState();
}

class _TodoItemState extends State<TodoItem> {
  late final FocusNode _focusNode;
  bool isEditing = false;
  String title = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    title = widget.todo.title;
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    _focusNode.addListener(handleFocusChange);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
  }

  void handleFocusChange() {
    if (_focusNode.hasFocus == false && isEditing) {
      //if change to title has occured save
      if (widget.todo.title != title) {
        widget.todo.todoTitle = title;

        print("focus changed");
        //save todo
        widget.updateTodo(widget.todo);
      }

      setState(() {
        isEditing = false;
      });
    }
  }

  bool isActive = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Checkbox(
          value: widget.todo.completed,
          onChanged: (_) {
            widget.todo.toggleComplete();
            widget.updateTodo(widget.todo);
          },
        ),
        trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever_sharp),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.deleteTodo(widget.todo);
            }),
        title: Text(widget.todo.title),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TodoListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  void onSettingsPress(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.settings);
  }

  final GlobalKey _draggableKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25))),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              builder: (context) => FractionallySizedBox(
                  heightFactor: 0.8,
                  child: Consumer<TodoListModel>(
                    builder: (context, todoListModel, child) =>
                        AddTodoModal(saveTodo: todoListModel.add),
                  )));
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todos'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              onPressed: () => onSettingsPress(context))
        ],
      ),
      body: Provider.of<TodoListModel>(context).isFetching
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Consumer<TodoListModel>(
                      builder: (context, todoListModel, child) =>
                          ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: todoListModel.todos.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                  LongPressDraggable(
                                    dragAnchor: DragAnchor.pointer,
                                    feedback: DraggableListItem(
                                      key: _draggableKey,
                                      title: todoListModel.todos[index].title,
                                    ),
                                    child: TodoItem(
                                        key: Key(todoListModel.todos[index].id
                                            .toString()),
                                        todo: todoListModel.todos[index],
                                        deleteTodo: todoListModel.delete,
                                        updateTodo: todoListModel.update),
                                  )),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
```

When I use a ListTile element in the DraggableListItem I get this error when I attempt to drag

```
'package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1873 pos 12: 'hasSize': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Material
lib/…/components/todo_item.dart:11
```

However, when I remove the ListTile widget and use only the Text Widget it drags successfully. Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: I think the issues is with the Expanded and Listview. Try to add ```physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()``` to your listview

Comment: Nope that gave the same error. Still looking through to see what about ListTile causes this.